# Linear regression

Tags: fitting, linear-algebra

I have a sequence of data:

```
 data = {0.647888, 0.522495, 0.454224, 0.417054, 0.396816, 0.385798, 0.379799, 0.376532, 0.374754, 0.373786, 0.373259, 0.372972}
```

How can I find asymptote of this sequence using linear regression? Can anybody help me how to start? I just got a clue: y=a+b/c^x. Should I use LinearModelFit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
data = {0.647888, 0.522495, 0.454224, 0.417054, 0.396816, 0.385798, 
   0.379799, 0.376532, 0.374754, 0.373786, 0.373259, 0.372972};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b/ c^x, {a, b, c}, x];
Normal@nlm
```

> $0.372629\, +0.505569 \,\, 1.8367^{-x}$

```
Limit[Normal[nlm], x -> Infinity]
```

> 0.372629

Comment: @hermano9, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: This data set is clearly not from any biology experiment as a plot of the data and the fit shows almost no variability from the predicted model.  An approximate 95% confidence interval for the value of the asymptote is found with `nlm["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"][[1]]` which shows as `{0.372629, 0.372629}`.